# Whats wrong with this CSS/HTML code?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS not modifying link properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543616/css-not-modifying-link-properties)

What's wrong with this code?   When I scroll over the navigation, everything pops up.  Additionally, I cant get the color of the text to be white (when I scroll over it, its white but when I back off, it stays black.  Also, check the bottom of my page, both columns are messed up…both should be equal width and length and should sit right next to each other.  Thanks for your help.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<style type="text/css">
    body html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#101010;
    font-family: helvetica;


}

p {
    margin:10px 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

}

p a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4e6f8c;

}


#wrapper {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background:#fff;
}

#header {
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#fff;
    height:518px;


}

#nav {
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#fff;
    width: 960px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 370px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
}
#nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:160px;
    float:left;
}


#nav li:hover {
    background-color: #24389b;
    height: 25px;


}

#nav a {

    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#nav a:link {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;


}

#nav a:visited{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;


}


#nav a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;



}

    #nav a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;

}



#nav a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#topcontent p
{
    color: #444444;

}


}
#leftcontent {
    float:left;
    width:480px;
    height: 1%;
    background:#fff;
}
h2 {
    margin:10px 0 0 20px;
    color: #24389b;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
#rightcontent {
    float:right;
    width:480px;
    background:#fff;
    height: 1%;
}
#footer {
    clear:both;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#fff;
}
#footer p {
    margin:0;
}
* html #footer {
    height:1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"><img src="pold.png" alt="Pold Logo" /></div>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Research">Research</a></li>
        <li><a href="Research">Publications</a></li>
        <li><a href="Research">Software</a></li>
        <li><a href="Research">People</a></li>
        <li><a href="Research">Volunteer</a></li>
        <li><a href="Research">Resources</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="topcontent">
    <p>The interests of our lab are generally centered around the study of learning and memory, decision making, and executive control.  Much of our work is focused on basic cognitive and neural mechanism, but we are also heavily involved in translational research not the mechanisms of neuropsychiatric disorders.  </p>

</div>
<div id="leftcontent">
    <h2>Funded Projects</h2>
        <p><a href="url">The Cognitive Atlas</a><br />(funded by NIMH RO1MH0822795)<br />The Cognitive Atlas project aims to develop anontology for cognitive processes through social <br />collaborative knowledge building.</p>

</div>
<div id="rightcontent">
    <h2>Center Grants</h2>
    <p><a href="url">Consortium for Neuropsychiatric Phenomics</a><br />(funded by NIH, PI: R. Bilder)<br />This Roadmap Interdisciplinary Research Consortium is leveraging the new discipline of phonemics to understand neuropsychiatric disorders at multiple levels, from genes to neural systems to </p>

</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One concrete problem at a time, please. This is too broad and localized.

Comment: You need to post a link to a working example of this.

Comment: Why not stick this into a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can play with it? Right now it's just a wall of text.

Comment: @BalusC Too broad _and_ too localised in one question? Well I never... ;-)

Comment: Before doing this all over again... I knew it looked familiar... it wouldn't be a bad idea to [refer back to the almost identical question you posted yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543616/css-not-modifying-link-properties) and respond to the nice folks who already tried to help you by providing five answers.

Comment: Step 1: [Validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) because fancy CSS doesn't work well with mal-formed documents. `Error found while checking this document as HTML 4.01 Strict!` and `1 Error, 8 warning(s) `  -- the 1 error is a doozy.

Comment: Also, just like it was pointed out to you yesterday, about a dozen times in your original question, you have two closing brackets `}` just after `#topcontent p`.

Comment: @StephenP Man! I hate that one.  It gives *no* helpful details >:(

Comment: My _"duplicate thread"_ flag was denied.  I guess if you simply add a bunch of superfluous junk to your original question, you're allowed to repost it.

Comment: @Sparky672 - the other question by your own admission is not an *exact duplicate*. It looks like he's solved one problem but hit another. I'm willing to give this a chance.

Comment: @Kev, I understand your reasoning, but IMHO, the OP should be at least participating in his first question before duplicating it within a poorly written "follow-up".

Comment: @Joseph _I hate that one. It gives no helpful details_ - it gives all the details you need to fix the issues raised.  Start by looking at the line numbers it refers you to.  Google the errors if necessary.  Break your code down into chunks that you understand and check if they validate; keep adding relatively small bits of code in and you'll soon gain some understanding what's going on.

Comment: @ChrisW Oh, I know.  I've figured it out before, but it's just one of those errors that you always wish had more info on it... it's just annoying XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything 'pops up' because you've got a height declaration in the hover attribute but not the original `li` definition:

```
#nav li:hover {
  background-color: #24389b;
  height: 25px;
}
```

The problem with columns is almost certainly because you've got the left to float left and the right hand one to float right - as far as I can remember, it will probably work best if you set them both to float left (there are lots of tutorials on 2 column liquid CSS designs; you should be able to adapt one to your needs)

I agree with @Joseph for your link colour issue - that's simple to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Little hard to tell what's going on... especially without seeing a demo of some kind, but as far as your hover text problem goes, you have the following:

```
#nav a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The problem is you are not wanting it to change the text when you hover over the link.  you want it to change color when you hover over the li like with your other rule.  Therefore, it should be like this:

```
#nav li:hover a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And Like I said, for the other stuff you should provide some kind of demo we can work with (and it might not be a bad idea making it a whole other question.)

---

#### EDIT

After seeing sg3s' comment I went back to see if there's a more compatible way and... there is!

```
#nav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
}
```

that mostly gets it... it's not perfect though.

Comment: You just lowered browser compatibility for no good reason.

Comment: @sg3s Yes.  Mostly I'll code for standards as opposed to compatibility unless specified.  The reasoning behind this is that browsers are moving toward compatibility and this will keep things up to date and useful and it removes things like IE6 hacks.  However, it is possible to do the above cross-browser and standards compliant (as far as I know :P).  So thank you for the input.  I've updated my answer

Comment: Yep, thats the way to go, but with that you try to style anything else (the ul, li) as little as possible and put those styles on the anchor.