# Help with CSS navigation, text positioning and spacing

Tags: html, css

All,

http://rich2233.comoj.com/

Three things I want to do:

1. I need the navigation bar to sit below the header.  This is probably
   a simple fix, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.
2. I need the text in the navigation to be centered vertically.
3. How do I put some space between the left and right columns?

Thanks for your help!  Below is the css code:

```
body,html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#101010;
    font-family: ‘Palatino Linotype’, ‘Book Antiqua’, Palatino, serif;


}

p {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;

}

p a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4e6f8c;

}


#wrapper {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background:#fff;
}

#header {
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#fff;
    height:137px;


}

#nav {
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#fff;
    width: 960px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #7c7c7c;
    text-align: center;


}

#nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
}

#nav li {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:160px;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px 10px / 10px 25px;
    border-radius: 25px 10px / 10px 25px;
}


#nav li:hover {
    background-color: #df220f;

}

#nav li:hover a{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#nav a {

    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#nav a:link {
    color: #7c7c7c;
    text-decoration: none;


}

#nav a:visited{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;


}


#nav a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;



}

    #nav a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#nav a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;

}


#leftcontent {
    float:left;
    width:710px;
    height: 300px;
    background:#df220f;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
    border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
    background-image:url('./images/main_placeholder.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center; 
}

h2 {
    margin:10px 0 0 20px;
    color: #24389b;
    font-size: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}

#rightcontent {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    background:#df220f;
    height: 1%;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
    border-radius: 1em 4em 1em 4em;
    height: 300px;
    background-image:url('./images/side_logo.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom center; 

}


#footer {
    clear:both;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#fff;
}

#footer p {
    margin:0;
    }

* html #footer {
    height:1px;
}
```

__*_*__*_*_ HTML EDIT:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css"
 href = "./style.css" media = "all" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"><img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Ultrabond Logo" /></div>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Research">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Research">Service<br />Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="Research">Service<br />Request</a></li>
        <li><a href="Research">Crack<br />Repair</a></li>
        <li><a href="Research">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="Research">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div id="leftcontent">

</div>
<div id="rightcontent">
    <p>Average cost of a windshield<br />replacement: $240</p><p>Average   <i>repair</i> cost: $60</p><p>Just another reason why<br />windshield <i>repair</i> makes sense</p>

</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Your link leads to an error page.

Comment: If you can't get your site back up, how about some markup?

Comment: Thanks everyone.   Not sure when the site will be back up, but hopefully soon.  I went ahead and made some of the suggestions listed below to the site.  I'll go ahead and edit the rest of the code.  Thanks again.

Comment: The site seems to be back up.

Comment: Rich, it would be great if you would "accept" some answers from the people trying to help you ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543616/css-not-modifying-link-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your link doesn't work

1) Don't set `position: absolute` for `nav ul`

2) Use `line-height` rule ([more detailed here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp))

3) Use `margin` or `padding`. Add `margin-left: <whatever you want>px` to `#rightcontent`

Answer (score 0):

For #nav li, you don't need to do display:inline and float: left. I would just use float: left, and then you can adjust spacing using margin.

No need to use position: absolute on #nav ul, but if you are going to use that here is a tip that helps me all the time. If you use position:absolute in a container that you haven't specifically set to position:relative, then the absolute positioning is set to the entire page.  However, if you have position:relative set on the container div, then you can absolutely position the child element anywhere within that div.

Like this:

```
#nav
{
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
position: relative;
}

#nav ul
{
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 200px;
}
```

this places the #nav ul 20px down from the top and 200px from the right within the #nav div.  If the #nav div didn't have position: relative on it.. then the #nav ul would be placed at 20px from the top of the page and 200px from the right of the page.